# Remove an object from list of child objects in Model by checkbox unset in Fluid

Tags: typo3, fluid, extbase

I have two Extbase models with 1:n relation. *Parent* relates to *Children* via `ObjectStorage`.

What I want to achieve: `editAction($parent)` which shows a list of all *Children* as entries with a checkbox (checked by default). User is allowed to unset any checkbox, submit a form and corresponding *Children* should be removed from *Parent* relation.

What I've done so far.
In a fluid I iterate over objects and output the checkboxes like this:

```
<f:for each="{parent.children}" as="child" iteration="iteration">
    <f:form.checkbox property="children.{iteration.index}" value="{child}" />
    <label>{child.title}</label>
</f:for>
```

This generates following HTML, which seems okay for me:

```
<input type="hidden" name="tx_myext_plugin[parent][children][0][__identity]" value="">
<input type="checkbox" name="tx_myext_plugin[parent][children][0][__identity]" value="135" checked="checked">
<label>child0-title</label>

<input type="hidden" name="tx_myext_plugin[parent][children][1][__identity]" value="">
<input type="checkbox" name="tx_myext_plugin[parent][children][1][__identity]" value="136" checked="checked">
<label>child1-title</label>
...
```

But when I unset the 2nd checkbox (uid=136) and submit a form, I get the following Exception

```
#1297759968: Exception while property mapping at property path "children.1": The identity property "" is no UID.
```

Which also seems logical, because there is that hidden input, that submits an empty value.

I think, I can hook somewhere in MVC-process and just filter out the entries with empty `__identity`, but is there a more elegant (e.g. best practice) way?

TYPO3 7.6.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller, you can make an `initialize*Action()` function. There you can filter out your empty values so that only values with an identity exsist.

```
public function initializeSaveAction()
{
  if ($this->request->hasArgument('parent')) {
   $parent = $this->request->getArgument('parent');
   foreach ($parent['children'] as $key => $child) {
     if (!$child['__identity']) unset($parent['children'][$key]);
   }
   $this->request->setArgument('parent', $parent);
  }
}
```

Now your `saveAction` is called after the `initializeSaveAction` and has only the selected children keept.

Comment: Yes, this is what I'm thinking about, just wanted to know if there are other recommended ways.

Comment: As I know this is the easy way. Maybe you can write an propertyMapper, but I think for such a simple think it is "to much".